# Buy On Amazon button

Tags: magento-1.9, product, javascript, css, product-page

I want to add "Buy on Amazon" button on my product page. I was successful in adding it with this code: `<a href="<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getamazonurl(); ?>"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/buy_on_amazon.png"></a>`

I created an attribute amazonurl & added it to the required attributes set. Now I can enter the link of my product in that field. Problem is I'm not selling all the products that are listed on my website, so I want this button to appear only if there is a value (URL) entered in attribute's field. How do I do it? Because currently it's appearing regardless of the value entered.

Comment: Hello @Mohit, Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
    <?php if($this->getProduct()->getamazonurl()){ ?>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getamazonurl(); ?>"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/buy_on_amazon.png"></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thanks, @Pawan.

Just wanted to add that my website already have "Buy Now" & "Add to Cart" button. This "Buy on Amazon" would be the third button & this will only appear if I add Amazon's URL. This shouldn't affect the default Buy Now & Add to Cart Buttons, they should appear regardless or along with Amazon's button. Would your code still work in this condition?

Comment: if you need "Buy on Amazon" along with add to cart, You can add my updated code.

Comment: just add above code at the end of file

Comment: Welcome @MohitSingh :)